# Show that $3^m+3^n+1$ can never be a perfect square for positive integer exponents (how to solve?)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I did the following: I set $3^m+3^n+1=x^2$ where $x\in\Bbb{N}$ and assumed it was true for positive integer exponents and for all whole numbers x so that I can later on prove it's invalidity with contradiction. Since $3^m+3^n+1$ is odd we can write $3^m+3^n+1 = (2k+1)^2$ for $k\in\Bbb{N}$. After a while I can't seem to prove it and I don't have any ideas on how else to approach this problem.

It would be very helpful if someone could give me a brief explanation on a possible proof since I'm currently practicing for a math competition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hint: Every odd square is congruent to $1$ mod $8$.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Try computing $3^m+3^n+1$ mod $8$ for a bunch of different (small) values of $m$ and $n$ and see what you get. Doing so will, hopefully, not only help you solve this problem, but will help show you how to think about other problems of a similar sort.

Comment: See if you can find a pattern when you divide $3^m$ by $8$

Comment: thank you for your useful advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every odd square is congruent to $1 \bmod 8$.

$3^m+3^n+1$ is odd.

$3^m+3^n+1 \bmod 8 \in \{3,5,7\}$ because $3^k \bmod 8 \in \{1,3\}$.

$1 \notin \{3,5,7\}$ implies $3^m+3^n+1$ is not a square.

Answer (score 1):

I was about to post an answer but Barry's comment (#3) moved me a bit.

1. Show that any odd square is $1 \pmod 8$. This can be done by a mere brute-force.
2. This gives $3^m + 3^n \equiv 0 \pmod 8$. Say (wlog) $m\geq n$. Then $8 \mid 3^n (3^{m-n} + 1) \implies 8 \mid 3^{m-n} + 1$.
3. What are the values of $3^{k} \pmod 8$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}?$. Compute that. This should be enough